# Database search field database

Tags: database, wordpress, search

I'm looking for a way to create a search box in wordpress, where visitors can search a number from the database. Is this possible? I have several package numbers in my database. I want to give my visitors the ability to search for their package number and request the information that comes with the number.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be done.

I suggest a different approach than using wp-exec. (I just looked at wp-exec website, and that plugin was created for WordPress 1.5, which means it hasn't been updated in about 5 years).

The content you want to display exists entirely outside of WordPress. I suggest you use a custom page template - see
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

In this case you would not use WordPress posts or pages or custom post types. On the custom page template you would write (or have written if you don't have the knowhow to do it yourself) PHP code to extract the info from the database and display it on a page.

For pages like that you would be using WordPress only as a container within which to display the results - they custom page would appear in the site Nav, The page of results would use the site's theme to display so it looks like the rest of the site.

But the code to display from the database would not use the WordPress loop. It would be PHP / MySQL data retrieval and display code.

I really doubt you will find a plugin that lets you display results from an external database, formatted the way you want them to appear. The reason is every external database is different, has different tables and table structures. And no two sites will want the external data visually displayed in the same way. So there is little generalization to encapsulate in a plugin as everyone wants it different.

I've created pages on some sites along the lines of what you want to do thus I know it can be done. But it requires writing custom code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I searched for a existing plug-in but it didn't exist. I'm trying to write my own PHP code now in a custom template. Can I use PHP code in, for example a HTML form? Because my wordpress is just showing the code instead of running it.